# Task status WaitingForActivation on call to Azure ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, active-directory, task-parallel-library, blocking, azure-resource-manager

I am new to Tasks in C#. I am trying to following the example regarding deploying an arm template to azure to start a virtual machine: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/arm-template-deployment/

One of the first operations given here is to get an authorization token by calling Active Directory. The code given in the link uses AcquireToken api which seems to be deprecated and currently I could find only AcquireTokenAsync. So I modified the code to create a Task and wait for it to complete:

```
private static string GetAuthorizationHeader()
{
    ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("{application-id}", "{password}");
    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}");

    Task<AuthenticationResult> acquireTokenTask = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
    Task.WhenAll(acquireTokenTask);
    AuthenticationResult result = acquireTokenTask.Result;
    if (result == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }

    string token = result.AccessToken;

    return token;
}
```

I was expecting thatTask.WhenAll blocks until the acquireTokenTask's status becomes "RanToCompletion". But even while the status is "WaitingForActivation" WhenAll is not blocking and the control goes to the next statement trying to get the acquireTokenTask.Result. This is resulting in an exception saying with the exception detail saying there was an error sending the request.

Questions:
1. Is there an error in sending the request that the status is not changing to "RanToCompletion"? I don't think this is the case since 2-3 runs out of 10 runs are succeeding with status "RanToCompletion" and I am able to get the result.
2. I thought Task.WhenAll blocks the thread until it runs to completion. Is this not true? If true, I am wondering how the control is passing to the next statement.
3. How can I resolve this issue and get the successful result on every run by the time the result is extracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought Task.WhenAll blocks the thread until it runs to completion. Is this not true?

`Task.WhenAll` returns an awaitable, which you need to `await` on. Currently, you pass your `Task` but don't await, which simply makes the code continue execution, until you block it with `Task.Result`. Although, that isn't nessacery at all here. `WhenAll` is ment to be used when you have multiple tasks that need to be asynchronously waited on. Here, you can simply await on the single `Task`:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeaderAsync()
{
    ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("{application-id}", "{password}");
    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}");

    AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                                            "https://management.azure.com/", cc);
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }

    string token = result.AccessToken;
    return token;
}
```

Comment: I want the thread to block. It looks like what I need is Task.WaitAll. Because if I use an await, the calling thread might return and another thread might continue the job. Please correct me if I am wrong: 
Task.WhenAll(taskInstance) == await taskInstance != Task.WaitAll(taskInstance). Task.WaitAll blocks the thread, right?

Comment: @Romonov `Task.WhenAll` will asynchronously yield, and `Task.WaitAll` will block. But why would you want to block? If you properly `await` the entire call-chain, you should be fine.

Comment: The function calling this is Main and Visual studio compiler is not allowing to put an await in Main. So I want to block.

Comment: @Romonov Ok, thats a special case. You can use `Task.Result` instead of `await`

Comment: This answer addresses only one of the questions. From the code supplied, it SHOULD be enough to await the call to AcquireTokenAsync. 
This is not the case and still leads to the issue that is implied in Question 1. I have await correctly applied to my call but it still continues when the status on the token  returned is "WaitingForActivation" not, "RanToCompletion". I only wish I had an answer but I have to suspect a fault in the call to AcquireTokenAsync which returns BEFORE it aquires the token !!!

Comment: @RobVonNesselrode This answer addresses all questions. OP was asking in regards to `Task.WhenAll`, not about awaiting the call to `AcquireTokenAsync`. I find it highly unlikely that it is prematurely returning since if you have access to the `Token` property, that means the returned task has completed.